# Как переписать формулу на C#?

Tags: c#

У меня есть формула из эксель. Как её записать на C#?

```
=Span*(1+(8*nomSAG^2)/(3*Span^2))/(1+(CableWT*Span^2)/(8*CableEA*nomSAG))*(1+'Cable Data'!$H$18/1000000*(ЕСЛИ(METk=0,73;-1;ЕСЛИ(METk=2,92;-10;ЕСЛИ(METk=4,38;-20;15)))-$O$12))
```

Написал следующий метод:

```
    public double GetLength(double span, double nomSAG, double cableEA, double thermalExpansion, double kFactor, double instTemp)
    {
        if (kFactor == 0.73)
        {
            kFactor = -1;
        }

        if (kFactor == 2.92)
        {
            kFactor = -10;
        }

        if (kFactor == 4.38)
        {
            kFactor = -20;
        }
        else
        {
            kFactor = 15;
        }

        return span * ( 1 + (8 * Math.Pow(nomSAG, 2)) / (3 * Math.Pow(span,2))) / (1 + (CableWT * Math.Pow(span,2)) / (8 * cableEA * nomSAG)) * (1 + thermalExpansion / 1000000 * kFactor - instTemp);
    }
```

Происходит ошибка при расчётах не могу понять почему

```
Span = 150
CableWT = 0.089 - константа
nomSag = 2.3
cableEa = 109374
thermalExpansion = 16.86
kFactor = 0.2
instTemp = 20
```

Ожидаемый результат 149.86

```
GetLength(150, 2.3,109374,16.86, 0.2, 20)
```

Comment: `Происходит ошибка при расчётах` как вы это поняли?

Comment: @aepot в эксель есть результаты расчёта и мои с ними не сходятся

Comment: Нужен воспроизводимый пример. То есть какие аргументы вы передаете в метод и какой результат ожидаете. То есть сам вызов этого метода. Иначе не воспроизвести.

Comment: @aepot, я поправил)

Comment: а span надо придумать самому?) покажите код, как вы это тестируете.

Comment: CableWT отсутствует в аргументах метода, откуда он берется?

Comment: @aepot, опять поправил)

Comment: что у вас получается в итоге?

Comment: @aepot, -2848,9141017357597

Comment: 149,93 - это приемлемый результат?

Comment: @aepot, вполне должен подойти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак не получается `149.86`, быть может неточно указаны входные данные. Нашел только где вы потеряли скобочки:

```
(kFactor - instTemp)
```

Но чтобы разобраться, пришлось переписать вашу формулу в сторону упрощения

```cs
const double CableWT = 0.089;

static double GetLength(double span, double nomSAG, double cableEA, double thermalExpansion, double kFactor, double instTemp)
{
    kFactor = Math.Round(kFactor, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) switch 
    { 
        0.73 => -1,
        2.92 => -10,
        4.38 => -20,
        _ => 15
    };

    return span * 
        (1 + 8 * nomSAG * nomSAG / (3 * span * span)) / 
        (1 + CableWT * span * span / (8 * cableEA * nomSAG)) * 
        (1 + thermalExpansion / 1000000 * (kFactor - instTemp));
}
```

Когда сравниваете `double`, не забывайте округлять, а лучше вообще не сравнивайте `double` на равенство, никогда. :)

Проверяем

```cs
double result = GetLength(150, 2.3, 109374, 16.86, 0.2, 20);
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString("F2"));
```

И ваш и мой вариант метода, выдают одинаковый результат

```
149,93
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1000000 * (kFactor - instTemp) //149.932202954269
```

Вы скобки пропустили =)
Всё остальное в рамках погрешности double, Excel может использует float или decimal, может ещё где-то double округлять... НО скорее всего float, что там под капотом у Excel знают только те, кто скрипты к нему пишут.
Если хотите точности - используйте decimal на всех этапах, но учтите что он медленнее.

Comment: вроде не секрет :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel